# How to use Kaffeine with open source drivers for nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia

How to use Kaffeine with open source drivers.

Normally, if I want to use kaffeine, on Ubuntu, I have to install the nvidia proprietary drivers. I was never comfortable with this but it worked so I used it.

Two weeks ago I up graded my PC. (New Motherboard, New CPU, More Ram) The proprietary drivers no longer works. (I get black screen after installing them) It is now time to figure out how to make things work with the open source drivers. The funny thing is almost every solution I found said install the proprietary drivers. If you get black screen and no
sound from kaffeine on Ubuntu, stay tuned. I also have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Kaffeine with open source drivers, disable deinterlace

On the Kaffeine menu bar, click Playback >>  Video >> Deinterlace

This answer was hidden obscurely on launchpad in a bug report.
The bug was reported numerous times but the answer is well hidden
and will only be found after considerable digging to find the
right article and sufficient reading to get to the point where 
the answer is finally revealed.